# how to use a list within spring security thymeleaf sec:authorize tag

Tags: spring-security, thymeleaf, spring-el

I am looping through a model attribute using the following:

```
<li class="nav-item" th:each="item : ${navigation}"
    sec:authorize='hasAnyAuthority("__${item.entitlements}__")'><a
    class="nav-link" th:href="${item.url}" th:text="${item.display}"></a></li>
```

where "item.entitlements" is a java List containing one element. on each item (at this time). I have also validated the entitlement on that list for each item and assigned in the spring security context is the same Authority.

I have additionally tried the following:

```
${#authorization.expression('hasAnyAuthority(__${item.entitlements}__)')}
```

Is this possible? If so what am I missing? Do i need to swap my database to use a String of comma seperated values?

I am using spring boot 2.1.8.RELEASE and the following thymeleaf spring security dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
    <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

which ends up being version 3.0.4.RELEASE

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the `item.entitlements` into a Comma separated string using Thymeleaf utility methods like `${#strings.listJoin(item.entitlements,',')}` and then use it in `hasAnyAuthority`